# Get SQL Server database name from guid

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have many databases errors logged with the following message:

> The transaction log for database '{GUID}' is full due to 'AVAILABILITY_REPLICA'

**How to get the correspondent database name?**

I've tried with Powershell:

```
Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName "..." -ServerName "..."
```

I can't find the GUID querying the sys.databases either:

```
SELECT * FROM master.sys.databases
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: What's the error code, Error 9002?

Comment: Try `(Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -ServerName <ServerName> | Where-Object {$_.DatabaseId -eq '<GUID>'}).DatabaseName`.

Comment: @JoyWang I've tried that before but unfortunately it doesn't work, no results are returned.

Comment: @RuiJarimba please try this code: `SELECT  * FROM sys.databases where service_broker_guid='{GUID}'` .

Comment: @LeonYue I'm not completely sure but it's likely to be error 9002

Comment: @LeonYue querying by `service_broker_guid` doesn't work either

Comment: @RuiJarimba  Maybe you reference this [Azure Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2922898/error-9002-the-transaction-log-for-database-full-due-to-availability) to troubleshoot the error: `The transaction log for database '%.*ls' is full due to 'AVAILABILITY_REPLICA'`. Wait for your update.

Comment: @RuiJarimba If the troubleshoot works for you, I will post it as the answer.

Comment: Hi, RuiJarimba, did the error solved now?

Comment: @LeonYue yes we sorted the problem in the meantime, we found the database name using Application Insights. I'll upvote your answer but I cannot accept it because I only tried the queries AFTER solving the issue, so I'm not sure how useful these could be. BTW I couldn't run the 2nd query (error)

Comment: @RuiJarimba Thanks. I'm glad your problem is solved. Do you mind me update the answer ?  Then you can accept it . Others can know your problem solved and reference from you. Or you can post and mark it yourself.  Thanks and have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

You reference this [Azure Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2922898/error-9002-the-transaction-log-for-database-full-due-to-availability) to troubleshoot the error: The transaction log for database '%.*ls' is full due to 'AVAILABILITY_REPLICA'

The error means the primary database in the primary replica is holding transactions that are not synced to other secondary replicas in the availability group.

If you can not find the database from the '{GUID}', the following  t-sql queries may be useful:

```
select name, log_reuse_wait,log_reuse_wait_desc from sys.databases;
```

Hope the query help you find the database.

For more details, please see: [Tag Archives: sql server full due to ‘AVAILABILITY_REPLICA’](https://sqlserverwarrior.wordpress.com/tag/sql-server-full-due-to-availability_replica/) .

**Update:**

Congratulations that you have solved the problem. You sorted the problem in the meantime, and found the database name using [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview).

Hope this helps.